# Implementing Discrete Wavelet Transformation in C

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, haar-wavelet, dwt

I am trying to implement DWT on gray images in C++. I saw an OpenCV implementation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072775/3024435.

The article at http://www.whydomath.org/node/wavlets/hwt.html was useful in understanding and implementing low/high pass filter using Haar wavelets.

Can somebody show how to convert the same to use db3 or db4???

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://www.whydomath.org/node/wavlets/generalwt.html. There, the implementation of Debauchie and Biorthogonal filters is explained in detail. It helped me a lot with implementing the DWT in C.